# python maximum Pairwise Product time limit error

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, limit

```
n = int(input(" "))

arr = list(map(int, input(" ").strip().split()))[:n]

a = arr[0];
b = arr[1];

for i in range (0, n):
    for j in range (i+1, n):
        if(arr[i] * arr[j] > a * b): 
            a = arr[i];
            b = arr[j];
                       
print("", a*b )
```

Hello, when I submit the above code to Corsera's coding judge system,

Failed case #4/17: time limit exceeded (Time used: 10.00/5.00, memory used: 22753280/2147483648.)

has been returned. How can I change it? Thank you.

Comment: reminds me of the knapsack problem. Much more difficult than a double loop with O(n2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would first sort the values and then take the two largest elements (O(nlog(n)) vs O(n^2)):

```
a, b = sorted(arr)[-2:]
```

But it would be useful to know what's the domain of the values in `arr` (because negative numbers would break my approach).

Comment: How would negative numbers break your approach?

Comment: @MatiasCicero (-10)*(-12) > 10 * 11. So given `arr=[-12,-10,10,11]` my approach would return `a=10, b=11`, which is wrong

Comment: Oh, gotcha! Thanks

Comment: Even with negative numbers in the mix, there are only four possibilities: a,b both negative, a,b both positive, a positive b negative, a negative b positive. You could apply your approach to each of these four possibilities, then keep the best of the four.

Comment: @Stef Sure, that would definitely work, thanks! Let me add it to my answer

Comment: Also, finding the max two values can be done in linear time; no real need for sorting.

Comment: @Stef you're very very right

Comment: thank you, I thought like this:


arr = sorted(arr)
ans = max(arr[0] * arr[1], arr[-2] * arr[-1])